# Rancher: how to add a qcow2 image?

Tags: docker

On internet I found this: [RancherVM Images](https://github.com/rancher/vm/blob/master/docs/images.md).

I have created the qcow2 image containing my edited Linux VM how to add to docker and see it from RancherVM web menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand how to do.
First create or convert a qcow2 compressed image(is the qemu format)
Then create a dockerfile like this and rename it  Dockerfile

```
FROM rancher/vm-base:0.0.1
COPY centos.img  /base_image/centos7.img
CMD ["-m 2002m"]
```

then import in docker,of course do this where you copied the image(in my case is /root/centos.img and pwd is root)

```
docker build -t "centos7:kvm"
```

Then open ranchervm webgui,do "create instance" and
put centos7:kvm in "image",setup other things how you like
it and click ok
You can run the docker image created via kvm via vnc on browser.